# Sklearn - define get_params() automatically

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to define a class that qualifies for an estimator in Sklearn, e.g.

```
class MyEstimator():
    def __init__(self,verbose=False):
        self.verbose = verbose

    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        return {
            'verbose': self.verbose,
        }

    def set_params(self, **parameters):
        for parameter, value in parameters.items():
            setattr(self, parameter, value)
        return self

    # Also def fit() and other stuff ...
```

## Question

`set_params()` could be defined without explicitly listing all parameter names. Is there a way to define `get_params()` in a similar way?

What I need from Sklearn is `GridsearchCV`, and from what I have tried, it seems `get_params` determines what parameters can be injected during cross validation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just inherit your class from [BaseEstimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html), which implements `get_params()` and `set_params()` for you.

Demo:

```
In [21]: from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin, RegressorMixin, ClusterMixin

In [22]: from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
    ...:
    ...: class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator):
    ...:     def __init__(self,verbose=False):
    ...:         self.verbose = verbose

In [23]: est = MyEstimator(verbose=True)

In [24]: est.get_params()
Out[24]: {'verbose': True}

In [25]: est.set_params(verbose=False)
Out[25]: MyEstimator(verbose=False)

In [26]: est.get_params()
Out[26]: {'verbose': False}
```

PS you may also want to inherit your estimator also from one of (`ClassifierMixin`, `RegressorMixin`, `ClusterMixin`), depending of what kind of estimator you are going to implement...

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into the Mixins too.

Comment: @diadochos, glad i could help :)